# Antonym of whopper

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that *whopper*, apart from the Burger King thing, means a great *lie* but I want to dwell on the other meaning, mostly colloquial, indicating a "very big thing of its kind", therefore expressions like the one below reported from the Cambridge dictionary:

[http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/whopper](http://Whopper)

> humorous informal something that is surprising because it is so much
>   bigger than the usual size: My nose is pretty big, but my Dad's got a
>   whopper.

I am wondering if the English language (American as well) has such a word but indicating the opposite: "something really small of its kind". Does whopper has an antonym of current usage?

Comment: Just to clarify, 'whopper' meaning a big lie is just one use of its general meaning of 'a remarkably big (anything)', and it's _always_ colloquial (or, as your dictionary says, humorous and informal).

Comment: In reference to prevarication, the best antonym I can think of is "little white lie".

Comment: @HotLicks: my question was for the other meaning...read at the end...

Answer (score 5):

To me, "whopper" is (not counting trademarks) most strongly associated with **fishing**, eg in the second definition here:

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/whopper

> 2 something unusually big
>
> The fish Mike caught was a whopper.

Sticking with that realm, you could have **"[tiddler](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tiddler)"** as the antonym:

> 1. A small fish, especially a stickleback or minnow.
>
> 1.1. A young or unusually small person or thing.
>       ‘she was only a little tiddler, ten years old’

Comment: +1 because this was the answer I'd have given if you hadn't beaten me to it.

Answer (score 1):

For another fishing analogy, "something really small of its kind" might be called a **minnow**.

> A small or insignificant person or organization.
>
> ‘the paper is a minnow in the national newspaper mass market’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/minnow

Answer (score 0):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/whopper) suggests:

> **Near Antonyms** lightweight, weakling, wimp, wisp; nonentity, twerp, whippersnapper
>
> **Antonyms** diminutive, dwarf, half-pint, midget, mite, peewee, pygmy (also pigmy), runt, shrimp

Personally, I'm fond of "wimpy."

Comment: Just to understand, so you can say "your nose is a wimpy"? Is it completely interchangeable?

Comment: :-)  Not quite, and I apologize.  "Whopper" is a noun and my preference is an adjective.  The noun form is "wimp."  E.G., "Your nose is a wimp" would be easily understood.

Comment: I try to be more specific. Can you add some evidence that wimp can be used as you say as a parfect antonym of whopper. For example, in "The Founder" Keaton says before paying at the restaurant: "well, that bill is a real whopper". Could you say "well, that bill is a wimp"?

Comment: If this [reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wimp) is not wrong, wimp means a weak and cowardly or unadventurous person ! So, "Your nose is a *wimp*" ?? Really ?

Comment: Yes.  As one example, "[Prius 12V Battery is a Wimp](http://www.cleanmpg.com/community/index.php?threads/23612/)."  Please note that as with all English idioms, there are times when a particular phrase makes sense and when it doesn't.  Your example is legitimate, but who would complain that a bill was small?

Comment: @SwastiGupta, yes, that is it's formal definition.  Why, then would the same reference (which I included in my answer) suggest it as an antonym for "whopper?"  The reason is that "whopper" is being used idiomatically.  Idiomatically, "wimp" means small, low strength, unsubstantial, etc.  So, yes, really.  A native English speaker would understand the phrase quite well.

Comment: @JBH Wimp is used in quite different contexts to whopper - often as a term of derision. You probably need to approach this question by asking the meaning of "antonym". Some people here seem to be obsessed with finding antonyms. Words do not have to have antonyms or synonyms.

Comment: To add to the confusion, in the UK "Wimpy" is a burger chain.

Comment: @MaxWilliams and again you've beaten me to it, I was all set to explain that, in a very real way, 'Wimpy' is the antonym of 'Whopper', it's the home-grown burger that we *cough* grew up with not the interloping transatlantic burger. Its the place where Gregory had heart-to-hearts with Maddy, its where all the rainy Saturdays of the 70s live.

Comment: @Spagirl, yes, I think the Wimpy brand in the UK is associated with dismal motorway service stations, and also, generally seen as being a bit crap (and failing - there can't be many left now).  So, "Less of a Whopper, more of a Wimpy" could work as a jokey reference, for Brits at least.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I really must get around to paying a visit to the one on my local High Street while it's still there to be visited.